# Tweet button from the same question always gives distinct link

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter

I pressed “share link to this question on Twitter" button in ["Origin of the meaning of joe"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/origin-of-the-meaning-of-joe/) (below FB button) from the same browser and session
receiving 4 posts with different links:

- http://t.co/DHoycBt
- http://t.co/oF96bBX
- http://t.co/oF96bBX
- http://t.co/RpbZwN6

Now, opening  the last link opens the text with a different link

- http://t.co/VLKH7tT
  which in its turn produces a message with another different link

  - http://t.co/XYZeutA

etc adiante, always a different link

Well, I hoped somewhere to get the same repeating link

Is it normal?
I just cannot get the logic of it, hence use

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. I sent this to Jarrod and he'll fix.

Comment: Why my reputation has not changed after upvotes of this my question? neither in E.SE nor in M.E.SE

Comment: @WebMAOhist votes on meta questions and answers do not affect reputation (except on Meta StackOverflow, which has its own reputation). See the FAQ, especially [this section](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).

Answer (score 4):

Totally my bug - a fix has been checked in and will be pushed out tonight.

Thanks!