# Tweet button from the same answer always gives distinct link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, feedback, twitter

The same issue, described in

- [Tweet button from the same question always gives distinct link](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/tweet-button-from-the-same-question-always-gives-distinct-link)

only when posting from answer (instead of question)

Checked on [my answer to question "What is a term for a system with rules without any exceptions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/what-is-a-term-for-a-system-with-rules-without-any-exceptions/13262#13262)

**Update:**
I opened follow-up subquestion

- [When is “tweet your answer” button available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/721/when-is-tweet-your-answer-button-available)

telling basically that I cannot document or reproduce this since this tweet button/link does not reappear in any of my answers.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this. I get the same link every time when I click the dynamic answer sharing links:

[image: dynamic answer sharing links]

Comment: Updated my question