# When is "tweet your answer" button available?

Tags: support, twitter

I was trying to reproduce and document the bug I reported in my question

- [Tweet button from the same answer always gives distinct link](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/717/tweet-button-from-the-same-answer-always-gives-distinct-link)

I opened [all my answers in EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3085/vgv8) one after another and this button did not appear (again) in any even from threads published by [@StackEnglish](http://twitter.com/#!/StackEnglish), for example,

- [What does "Alien" actually mean?](http://twitter.com/#!/StackEnglish/status/38287310290288640)

When does this functionality of tweeting button appear in an answer?
For example, I it did appear before while I tweeted:

- [My answer to Stack Exchange English Language and Usage Q: What is a term for a system with rules without any exceptions?](http://twitter.com/#!/vgv8/status/38693818794643456)

And even in that answer this button/link of tweeting does not reappear.
Though it would have been convenient to preserve it for multiple tweeting or getting a link for copying to other boards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available

- a certain random percentage of the time, scaled to your reputation
- for about an hour
- if your post is > 400 chars
- on your posts only (eg it is only visible to you)